# How do I solve an unknown column database error?

Tags: php, sql

Here is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
function update()
    {
        $this->name   = $_POST['txtname'];
        $this->address = $_POST['txtaddr'];
        $sql1 = "update reg set adress='$this->address' where name='$this->name'";
        $Q1 = $this->db->query($sql1);
        echo "Updated Successfully";
    }
```

This is the error I receive when running it:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'adress' in 'field list'

update reg set adress='mumbai' where name='sagar'

Filename: C:\wamp\www\sagar\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

What steps can I take to debug something like this?

Answer (score 3):

This means, in your table `reg`, there is no column by the name `adress` Check the spelling of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Check `address` column name/spelling in database table `reg`.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you get an error of type "Unknown column [columnName] in [tablename]" you should carefully review your sql for errors:check

1. spelling
2. column names
3. make sure you are selecting from the correct table or view
4. make sure you are in the correct database

In this specific case it appears your column name may be incorrect.